# Packages have unmet dependencies, why?

Tags: apt, ppa, dependencies

I get this error while trying to install a package as follows:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:v-launchpad-jochen-sprickerhof-de/pcl
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libpcl-all
```

The first two don't issue any error message, but the last one gives:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:  libpcl-all : Depends: libpcl-
1.3-all but it is not going to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have 
held broken packages.
```

How is that even possible? If package xxx depends on package yyy, why isn't yyy installed then? Usually, when you run `apt-get install xxx` it will automatically install all packages xxx depends on. What may prevent it from doing so?

```
but it is not going to be installed
```

well **why** isn't it?

Comment: Have you tried to apt-get install the dependency manually? Did it give you any error?

Comment: Probably because it can't be found.  Check `apt-cache policy yyy` to find out.